# ModalPopupExtender click through on Droid Bionic

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I use the modalpopupextender through out my application for adding records to gridviews. Recently I started testing it on my Droid Bionic and if I have for example a textbox inside the modal window and there are links underneath said textbox it will "click" the link instead of setting focus on the textbox. No events are fired when the link is clicked, but it does prevent me from selecting the control.

After fighting with the CSS for a while I decided to just remove all modal windows from the application and put them their own pages, but before i go through the trouble of doing that I was hoping someone else had run into this problem, and fixed it.

Comment: add some sample code, or better yet a jsfiddle if you expect any kind of meaningful help...